# Showing whether or not the mapping $T(x,y,z) = (y \sin x, z \cos y, xy)$ is onto.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

How can I show whether or not the mapping $T(x,y,z) = (y \sin x, z \cos y, xy)$ is onto (surjective)?

Comment: onto $\mathbb{R}^3$? This map is not linear.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that (my teacher always uses the word "onto" on its own, so I guess that habit trickled down to me).

Comment: And I changed the tag to "functions" instead of linear algebra.

Comment: Hint: can $T$ attain $(1,0,0)$?

Comment: Oh, I see.  It can't attain $(1,0,0)$ because $xy = 0$ necessarily implies $y \sin x = 0 \ne 1$.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show this is not surjective.  For one way to do this look at the first and last coordinates in the image: $(y\sin(x),xy)$.  These only depend on $x$ and $y$ so you would need $S(x,y)=(y\sin(x),xy)$ to be onto $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $xy=0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$, so you can only get a first coordinate of $0$ when the last coordinate is $0$, in particular there is no $(x,y)$ so that $S(x,y)=(1,0)$.

Comment: For future reference, is there any real method to determining whether or not a function is surjective, or is it only a matter of finding (or not finding) counterexamples?

Comment: Sometimes there is a very straightforward method (like with linear functions on finite dimensional spaces).  Sometimes there are tricks and theorems that tell you (sometimes you can use theorems in topology to show a map must be onto using connectedness or something).  I'd say in general though you have to go by definition and prove every point is in the image or find a counterexample.